# Would it be confusing for users to use chips in a table that have two different behaviours in two separate columns?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, usability-testing, human-interface-guideline

I'm creating a table where users review and refine relevant keywords and tags for a list of profiles. There are separate columns for keywords and another for tags. For each word, I want to use chips (material UI) to separate them within a table cell. In the keyword column, the chips should be selectable (multiple selection), so that I can do bulk actions on them, while for the tags column, to allow users to delete and add tags (chips).

My question is, whether it would be confusing for users if these chips had different behaviours depending on the column? Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: I think both the columns are not much different on functionality.
Keywords column: One may add the keywords and remove the irrelevant ones from it.
Tags column: One may add relevant tags and remove irrelevant ones from it

So adding the 'x' to keywords also would solve the issue. yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually resolved this a while ago but I didn't post my solution. It was similar to Kishan's suggestion, I just added an X to keywords, but the keyword would be moved into another container of irrelevant keywords when user clicks on X (as the user needed to see that list of "blacklisted" keywords). On the other hand, users didn't need the same thing for tags, so they were just removed from the column.